# My form for uploading photos does not work. Django

Tags: django, forms

When I use the form provided by django admin everything works fine. But after creating my own form, django does not write data to my model. Is something missing in my code?

**Models.py**

```
class Offert(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='app/documents/')
```

**forms.py**

```
class OffertFormCV(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Offert
        fields = ( 'name',
                   'file')
```

**views.py**

```
def my_views(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OffertFormCV(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:thank_you_page'))

    else:
        form = OffertFormCV()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'form_application.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls', namespace='app'))
]  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/media')
```

**form_application.html**

```
                  <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                  </form>
```

After sending the form, nothing happens. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form to be able to upload files:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```